# BIC not finding a maximum

Tags: r, clustering, bic

I was trying to apply BIC to my dataset to find the ideal number of clusters and model that best fits my data, in order to use EM algorithm, but it´s not reaching a maximum, even if I increase the max number of components to 20. They keep increasing slowly but they don´t decrease. I have previously performed k-means and hierarchical clusterings which only required around 13 clusters.

[image]

For context, I used PCA to reduce the dimension of my data (I had 35 variables and reduced them to 20 principal components). Then, I extracted the scores from those 20 components, and applied BIC.

This is the relevant part of the code I used:

```
data.transf <- as.data.frame(dados.PCA$scores[,1:20]) 
BIC <- mclustBIC(data.transf,G=1:15)
```

The picture above was created using the command:

```
plot(BIC, xlab="number of clusters")
```

Is there something wrong? How should I proceed? It would be impractical to keep increasing the number of clusters more, as my dataset has 50.000 samples, and the code already takes a while to run.

Comment: I wouldn't use model based clustering or BIC or anything similar for clustering.  You already did hierarchical clustering.  Look at various possible solutions and ask yourself which one helps you the most.

Comment: @PeterFlom There are good reasons for preferring model based clustering over hierarchical clustering and k-means in many situations. Particularly with model-based clustering you can have clusters with different within-cluster variation and shape. In my study https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11634-021-00478-z different methods are best for different data, but if any method can be called "overall winner", it'd be model-based clustering (see Table 4 in particular).

Comment: @PeterFlom Also, the BIC has problems but pretty much every other method to automatically determine the number of clusters has worse problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) The number of clusters problem is very difficult (as is the model selection problem in unsupervised learning). There are major difficulties and ambiguities even with the definition of what the "true number of clusters" or theoretically best model actually is (see the paper linked at the end). In many situations data can be meaningfully or at least usefully split up into a low as well as a much larger number of clusters, and which one is better really depends on what you want to use the clustering for and all kinds of background information that is obviously not taken into account by any automatic method, BIC or other. Also, many data sets are genuinely ambiguous and quite different clusterings can be seen as appropriate. I will never trust any formal criterion on its own; I will always look at criteria, different methods, and all kinds of visualisation, and also think about interpretability and practical use of any "competitor".

(2) Looking for a unique "optimal" clustering, nothing in the question actually makes sure that the data should have less than 20 clusters. Why might it not be 25, 50, or 200? OK, other methods could do with 13 clusters according to what you write (although it is not explained how you found that out), but on what basis can you argue that this is really better than what the BIC would deliver? You say it's "impractical" to go beyond 20, which is fair enough, but this does by no means imply that BIC should give you less than 20. Obviously you can say, more than 20 is impractical, so you choose 20 because BIC says 20 is best if you constrain search to less than or equal to 20. You might find this unsatisfactory but there is no reason to think that there is a "truly" better clustering with a smaller number of clusters.

(3) You could probably compute the BIC with larger numbers of clusters not computing all covariance matrix models, for example you could run only VEV and EEV (or only one of them), which seem to be best at 20 clusters. Also if you're using the `Mclust` function in R, you may decrease the subset size in `initialization` or play around with other algorithm tuning in order to ease the computation effort.

(4) That said, a known (but not very well known) problem with BIC for choosing the number of clusters is that this is critically dependent on the model assumption. What happens is this: The Gaussian mixture model for model-based clustering assumes the mixture components to be Gaussian. Now Gaussian mixtures are very flexible, so if you come across a group of points that could reasonably be interpreted as a cluster but is non-Gaussian (for example it may be unimodal but somewhat skew), the distribution within such a cluster can very well be approximated by a mixture of several Gaussians (this holds for pretty much every non-Gaussian distribution). If there are enough observations for the BIC to "see" this (and enough observations for fitting several Gaussians to this group), the BIC will decide to approximate this group with several Gaussians. There is in principle nothing wrong with this, as this will improve the "fit" of the data set by a mixture of Gaussians, which actually is the aim of the BIC. However, it is important to note that what breaks down here is the *interpretation of each mixture component as a cluster on its own*, as these mixture components may not be separated in the way you'd expect clusters to be separated.

If your data set is large, this is a general problem with using the BIC for cluster analysis, as in reality nothing is perfectly normal, and if anything isn't, from a certain number of observations onward the BIC will add mixture components. 50,000 observations are apparently big enough to let the BIC go beyond 20 in this way (I'm not very surprised as 1,000 observations per cluster, say, is still a very solid number in 20 dimensions). As I said, there is no guarantee that the number of meaningful clusters in your data is in fact lower, however I'd also expect that the BIC will put several mixture components on something that in your application maybe should be interpreted as only one cluster.

(5) What can you do? The mclust package also offers the ICL, a different criterion for model selection. The ICL suffers less from the issue with the BIC mentioned above; it tends to leave a cluster together if splitting up doesn't lead to mixture components that don't have a certain amount of separation (actually it penalises lack of separation). There's the function `mclustICL` that can be used for optimising the ICL.

(6) You could use visualisation and background knowledge to explore local BIC-optima such as EEV-2 and VEV-8. As I wrote, blindly optimising a criterion in clustering has many issues, and depending on what you want to use the clusters for and what the meaning of the data is, you may prefer something that is not a global optimum. (I do admit that this is problematic if you want something "objective" that doesn't depend on irreproducible researcher judgement.)

(7) Addressing the problem of the BIC delivering too many "clusters", I have done some work on merging mixture components so that you end up with a clustering in which a cluster is made up by potentially several mixture components as estimated by BIC, as long as these components are not well separated and/or their mixture is still unimodal. See  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11634-010-0058-3
(a free version should be on ResearchGate, maybe also elsewhere). This is implemented in the fpc-package, function `mergenormals`. (The mclust authors also have such a thing that was published at about the same time as mine, function `clustCombi` in mclust.)

Some general considerations regarding the choice of the best clustering and the number of clusters problem (background for what I claim above) are in my Handbook of Cluster Analysis chapter "Clustering strategy and method selection" [(free version on arxiv)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02059).